# Apache Storm as Cluster Manager

Tags: java, apache-storm, scaling, microservices

We use Apache Storm as a core technology in our project and have running production cluster with operations ppl who know how to support it.

At the same time we also have lots of services/components that doesn't really fit into 'realtime computation system' description but would also benefit from such features of Storm Cluster as automatic scaling, multi nodes deployment and recovery of any crashed worker processes.

So there's a thought to implement a simple wrapper that will start a regular java application as a topology and use Storm as cluster management system.

What do you think is it a good idea or not from architectural point of view?

Comment: Sound not like a good idea to me... You should go with something like Mesos or YARN and embed Strom there.(eg.: https://github.com/yahoo/storm-yarn)